# Disable server signature on nginx with modsecurity

Tags: nginx, http-headers, mod-security

I have compiled modsecurity and headers_more_module with nginx(1.13.6) on my ubuntu server. When modsecurity is not enabled at the nginx configuration, I am able to hide the origin server's name in the server responses:

`Server: nginx`

However, when modsecurity is enabled, I am getting the header in every response.
How can I disable showing the server's signature with modsecurity enabled? Is there anything that should be modified in the modsecurity configuration to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recompiling nginx with modsecurity-nginx connector worked. Followed this link to do this: 
[compile nginx and modsecurity with nginx-modsecurity connector](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/nginx-with-libmodsecurity-and-owasp-modsecurity-core-rule-set-on-ubuntu-1604/) and included headers_more_module while compiling nginx.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on Ubuntu the following should work:

1. Install `nginx-extras`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
   ```
2. Edit `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` and in the `http` block add:

   ```
   http {
       more_set_headers "Server: My_Custom_Server_Name";
       server_tokens off;
   }
   ```
3. Restart nginx

   ```
   sudo service nginx restart
   ```

Comment: I am on an ubuntu server. But, nginx-extras will work only if nginx was installed using apt-get. I have manually compiled nginx. Also, I need a solution for removing the header in the presence of modsecurity rather than just nginx.

Comment: Also worked for me on a Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 0):

If using ModSecurity v2.0 - v2.9, add this to the .conf file:

```
 SecServerSignature FakeServer
```

Comment: Should I recompile modsecurity again to add this? I added this after compiling it and now I am getting 2 headers, "Server: nginx and Server: FakeServer".

Comment: Could you please tell me when(to tweak the modsecurity configuration during compilation) and exactly which config file to add SecServerSignature?